# How to receive ,send and store a json array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I want to get a json array from ajax call and store it in a array . I tried this code but it doest not work .The alert shows me the string **{"value":[1]},{"value":[2]}** .I need this string to be converted in JSON array and stored in myData .Is there any problem about the responseJSON or any other thing ? Plz help

**making a call**

```js
setInterval(function showUser(str) {
 str="1";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
           
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        
    
    var myData=(xmlhttp.responseJSON);
            
    window.alert(myData);
   
      
   
            }
        
        xmlhttp.open("GET","new.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
  
}, 1000)
```

and this is the code for **new.php**

```js
<?php


$conn =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("webauth");
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
        echo '"{values":['.$row['value'].']}'.',';
 }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the JSON array properly, because you don't have the `[ ]` around the array elements. You should just construct a PHP array and call `json_encode` on it.

```
$result = array('values' => array());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $result['values'][] = $row['value'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

When you alert `myData`, it should show

```
{ values: [1, 2] }
```